# Why can I see "hiberfil.sys" when I don't have an option to hibernate?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I have a 3.5GB `hiberfil.sys` file on my OS drive but am unsure why it is there. I understand it is used for system hibernation, I also understand I can [disable it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15140/what-is-hiberfil.sys-and-how-do-i-delete-it/).

The thing is, on my machine I don't even seem to have the option to hibernate (Win 10 Ent). If hibernating isn't an option, why do I have this file on my drive taking up space? If hibernating is an option, how do you initiate it?

[image: Shutdown menu]#

Custom PC with following specs:

- Motherboard: ASUS Maximus VII Formula
- CPU: Intel Core i3 4130 1150 Socket - Haswell 22nm
- Memory: Corsair Vengance 8GB DDR3 Dual Channel (2 x 4GB sticks)
- GPU: EVGA GeForce 8800 GT
- PSU: Corsair RM550

Comment: What is the make and model of PC?

Comment: Motherboard: ASUS Maximus VII Formula | CPU:  Intel Core i3 4130 1150 Socket - Haswell 22nm | Memory: Corsair Vengance 8GB DDR3 Dual Channel (2 x 4GB sticks) | GPU: EVGA GeForce 8800 GT | PSU:  Corsair RM550

Comment: Your screenshot isn't clear.  It makes no mention of hibernate.  Have you attempted to enable hibernation then disable it?

Comment: Like I said in the question, I don't have an option to hibernate, that's why there is no mention of it in the screenshot. I also cannot find an option to en/disable hibernation anywhere. Have looked in Power Options in Control Panel but couldn't find anything.

Comment: see this...http://winaero.com/blog/add-hibernate-to-the-start-menu-in-windows-10/

Comment: @Moab I know it is. I am asking why the file is on my drive when hibernating the machine doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hiberfil.sys` is not only used for hibernate, but also hybrid sleep and fast startup

And for the hibernate option on the power menu, go to `Power Options` and click `Choose what the power buttons do` on the left, and then:

[image]

Comment: To add from Windows 8 and above,  hybrid booting meant  that when you hit shutdown button it would actually hibernate along with some other things.

Comment: I see. So hibernate is effectively part of the normal shutdown procedure now? Now it makes sense why I have the file even without the option to hibernate.